# Can globalBinding tag be included in the root element?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

i have following external binding file -

`<jxb:bindings version="1.0"`
 
`xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"`
 
`xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`
 
`xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"`
 
`jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"`
 
`>`
 
`<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="xyz" node="/xs:schema">`
 
`<jxb:globalBindings>`
 
`<xjc:serializable/>`
 
`</jxb:globalBindings>`
 
`<jxb:schemaBindings>`
 
`<jxb:package name="abc"/>`
 
`</jxb:schemaBindings>`
 
`</jxb:bindings>`
 
`</jxb:bindings>`

i need to place jxb:globalBindings tag in root jxb:bindings

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the correct place for it

```
a <bindings> element can contain arbitrary number of binding declarations or nested <bindings> elements
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_1_0.xsd